# jQuery SVG plugin transform animation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm trying to use the jQuery SVG plugin to animate some stuff — scaling and whatnot. I'm totally new to SVG.

```
var params = {};
params['svgTransform'] = ['scale(1)', 'scale(1.5)'];
$('#TX', svg.root()).animate(params);
```

This is copied almost *verbatim* from the *developer of the plugin*.

Yet when it runs, I'm getting this:

```
4TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'f.easing[i.animatedProperties[this.prop]](this.state,c,0,1,i.duration)')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check for existence of an element with ID="TX" in your SVG document.

Anyway, I must say that sometimes I found *very* difficult to remember *where* to code specific behaviour: there are so many choices, among XML (plain SVG), plain JavaScript+DOM (but what DOM?), jQuery specific, jQuery+SVG.... And all of these with their details... It's daunting! I hope it will be rewarding in the end.

BTW I found that Chrome give a good IDE to workout problems (I'm on Linux now...). Hit Ctrl+Shift+I to enter the debugger and see whatever error...

Answer (score 0):

maybe it doesn't support array inside animate arg object. can you try :

```
var params = {};
params['svgTransform'] = 'scale(1.5)';
$('#TX', svg.root()).animate(params);
```